# How to handle per-user signing keys when validating a JWT?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jwt

I have a web application where the user logs in with a back-end Spring MVC server. I implemented it using JWT and it works (fine) like this:

1. The user inserts username and password in a login form.
2. I hash the password using sha256 and call a login endpoint sending username and sha256(password) in my MVC.
3. The endpoint checks whether the user is present and password is okay (password are saved as sha256(password)), if yes, I generate a JWT that expires in one hour and I set a field username in its payload. The key I use for the JWT is a user dependent key, it is a salt randomly generated when I create the user and is saved in the DB. Finally I send the JWT to the browser
4. The browser saves the JWT in `localstorage`
5. For every call to the back-end asking for data I should use the JWT from now on

My problem is on how to let the server know who is calling the endpoint by using only the JWT?

Is it possible to get the username field in the payload without the signing key? The reason why I need to know which user triggered it, is because I have to retrieve the correct key to validate the JWT, which is user dependent.

My idea is to send for every request the JWT and the username. Is it the right way of doing it or it is not needed and I am missing something of this JWT thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JWT family of specification allow you have tokens ([Learn JSON Web Tokens](https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/)) that are:

- just encoded in a friendly format for use in HTTP systems (base64url encoding)
- signed and encoded
- encrypted and encoded
- signed, encrypted and encoded

It seems you went with signed tokens that are then encoded in base64url encoding so that they are easier to transmit over HTTP. With this approach you have access to the data contained with them before actually needing to validate the signature. See [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) for an example, you'll be able to see the contents of a sample token (header and payload) without actually performing the signature validation.

Based on this you would be able to include something in the token that allows you to know which signing key to use to validate the signature. The [`kid` standard claim](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.4) seems a good candidate in terms of where to include that information.

> The "kid" (key ID) Header Parameter is a hint indicating which key was used to secure the JWS.

Additionally, a few notes on your implementation; given that user provided passwords will generally have little entropy (randomness) you should not store a direct hash of the password. Instead you should use a suitable library that salts the password before hashing and that also uses an algorithm aimed specifically at password hashing - something like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

---

As an additional note, going with JWT's that are just signed and encoded is the most widespread approach and the one generally recommended. You would only need to consider the use of JWT encryption, which adds significant complexity, if you need to include sensitive information in the token itself.